# DefinedTypes not found in 'Assembly'. Are you missing any reference

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I am using reflection to invoke methods dynamically based on string method and class names. For this I loop through all the assemblies to find the class name given and invoke the method in it. While looping through assemblies like below

```
foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    type = asm.DefinedTypes.Where(t => string.Compare(t.Name, pTypeName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0).FirstOrDefault();
    if (type != null) //If the type is found, stop looping through the assemblies
        break;
}
```

I get error "DefinedTypes not found in 'Assembly'".

Comment: Added in .NET 4.5, along with the TypeInfo class that made the method necessary.  Use GetTypes() instead.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue. My project was targeting .Net 4. When I changed the target framework to .Net 4.6, the issue got resolved.